# Reescribir acción controlador Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy usando como gestor backoffice Sonata Admin (v 3.43) y tengo una entidad PHP la cual tiene el siguiente campo:

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Image()
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string")
 */
private $imagen;
```

Es decir, tengo un campo en dicha clase que apuntará a la ruta de una imagen (dicha ruta será la almacenada en la BBDD).

He creado un controlador propio solo para definir las acciones de creación y 
   borrado (para así eliminar la imagen del server cuando si se elimina un 
   post).

El problema está entonces en **¿Como puedo sobrescribir un método 
   'predefinido' por Sonata con uno que defina yo en el controlador 
   personalizado para una entidad?**

He seguido estos dos enlaces, pero en ambos lo que se trata es crear una nueva opción de gestión en lugar de redefinir una ya existente.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224076/how-to-create-a-custom-form-using-crud-controller-in-sonata-admin-bundle

Answer (score 1):

Hace mucho que no uso Sonata, pero creo la manera de sobrescribir el método existente era igual que el ejemplo que has puesto con un método custom.

Sobrescribes el CreateAction (por ejemplo), escribes el código necesario para gestionar las imágenes y llamas al método padre (parent::CreateAction). O bueno, puedes sobreescribir todo el método integramente si prefieres.

```
class TestAdminController extends CRUDController
{
    public function createAction($id)
    {
        // codigo que necesitas para la imágen

       parent::createAction(); // para que ejecute lo que hace el método create padre de Sonata
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, si solamente quieres eliminar la imagen del disco, ¿no es más sencillo hacerlo a través de eventos?

En el la definición de la clase Admin para cada entidad puedes implementar los eventos de Sonata. Para la entidad Test llamas al evento postUpdate y postRemove y haces ahí lo que necesites con las imágenes sin necesidad de sobrescribir el Controller.

```
class TestAdmin extends...
{
    public function postUpdate(...)
    {
    // codigo que necesitas 
    }

    public function postRemove(...)
    {
    // codigo que necesitas 
    }
}
```

Comment: coincido con el uso de los eventos de postUpdate y postRemove en el admin. Te diria que revises `https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/cookbook/recipe_file_uploads.html`.